# django db schema - creating tasks of different types, each w/ different fields

Tags: database, django, database-design, django-models

What's the best DB design, using django, for the following scenario:

I have a list of computers in the database. I want to add a task to be executed by a computer. There are different tasks, each with different fields. For example, one might be "install program", which has a ForeignKey to the Program table, where the entries contain info on how to install the program. Or it might be like "change setting", containing ForeignKey to a Setting table.

I was thinking of having a TaskType with (name, description), but to make the above work, each one would have to have foreign key to Program and Setting, even if the task doesn't use either. that seems not the best... is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

As described, your conceptual schema involves the following predicates:

- **task** exists
- **computer** exists
- **setting** exists
- **program** exists
- **task** executes on **computer**
- **task** is to change **setting**
- **task** is to install **program**

You also appear to one constraint, you need to judge how significant it is:

- | P6 join P7 |  = 0  -- there is no **task** to install **program** and change **setting**

Some might suggest the natural Django solution would be to use [model inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) to represent a base "Task" model, with two subclasses - "InstallTask" and "SettingTask".   You then either carry the 
"computer" as an attribute of the base class, or alternatively have another model "ComputerTask" or such.

Using model inheritance would afford some benefits, including (1) getting some support for creating the base Task at the same time as you create, say, the ChangeTask, and (2) encouraging, but not enforcing, maintenance of the constraint.

However, in my experience, there are conceptual problems with model inheritance, and you may encounter surprising and unwanted behavior, for example, updating tasks.   In this case, I might simply place Task 1:1 with InstallTask and 1:1 with SettingTask.    This is actually more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your exact issue (not enough data) so my answer will be little abstract (or high level) :)

IMHO, looks like you may be interested in the [generic relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) that are working with content types.

Using this feature will give you an option to link from one mode to any other,
so you can have different Objects as the reference.